# Delete Scheduled Task Without Admin Rights

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I've created a scheduled task using the example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125910/run-any-file-with-vbs-at-a-specific-time) question, but don't seem to be able to end it now. Getting the "Syntax error" when I run the following code found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490996(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

```
schtasks /delete /tn * /f
```

I also tried

```
schtasks /delete /tn "Execute Notepad by Hackoo" /f
```

I don't have admin rights and am wondering if that's why I can't delete the task.

Please let me know if you can help me stop Notepad from opening every minute.

Thanks!

Comment: "I don't have admin rights (probably for a reason)" - why don't you have local admin rights on your own machine? And what "reason" are you referring to?

Comment: Our company has very strict security policies, so only IT people have admin rights. I'm not one of them. Is there a way to delete the task by running .vbs?

Comment: No, there isn't - otherwise anyone could get around not having admin-rights by running a script.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Why would it be possible to create tasks using vbscript but not delete them? seems illogical

Comment: You are not required to be an administrator. If you are allowed to delete a task then you'll be allowed to. You can delete anything you create. Why would the second one work? You have a task with that name?

Comment: Actually, I just deleted it using the Command Prompt! I was running it as .vbs before...Schtasks /delete /TN "Execute Notepad by Hackoo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT :**

```
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Taskname="Test Task"
objShell.Run "Schtasks /delete /TN "&""""&Taskname&""""&" /F",0,True
```

If the code does not work for you,fix your access.
See here = [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22413520/9556248)

So,test the code below :

```
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "SchTasks /Create /SC WEEKLY /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI /TN ""Test Task"" /TR ""C:\CPU.cmd"" /ST 10:10", 0
'==> Check it.
Taskname="Test Task"
objShell.Run "Schtasks /delete /TN "&""""&Taskname&""""
' Or =
'objShell.Run "Schtasks /delete /TN "&""""&Taskname&""""&" /F",0,True
```

Comment: See my new changes.

Comment: Thanks, scientist_7! Both ways work. objShell.Run "Schtasks /delete /TN "&""""&Taskname&"""" opens cmd and asks if I'm sure I want to delete the task. objShell.Run "Schtasks /delete /TN "&""""&Taskname&""""&" /F",0,True just deletes it.

Answer (score 1):

```
schtasks /delete /tn * /f
```

You'll get a syntax error for this because `schtasks.exe` does not allow wildcards (`*`) to be used for the `/TN` option.

However...

```
schtasks /delete /tn "Execute Notepad by Hackoo" /f
```

...this command *is valid*, but you need elevated/administrative rights to delete a system-registered scheduled task.

This is documented in the help for `schtasks /?` (emphasis mine):

> Enables an **administrator** to create, delete, query, change, run and end scheduled tasks on a local or remote system.

Answer (score 1):

For noobs like me... You can delete a task you've created. Go to **Command Prompt** and run

`Schtasks /delete /TN "taskname"`

I was trying to run that thru .vbs

Comment: this doesn't work anymore on tasks I've created using vbscript. Getting "access is denied" in Command Prompt.